# How to Synchronize Javascript object with indexed DB?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, indexeddb

I have code bellow

```
var jsonData='{              
           "results":[            
              {                    
                "id":"460",         
                "name":"Widget 1",   
                "loc":"Shed"          
              },{                    
                "id":"460",         
                "name":"Widget 2",   
                "loc":"Shed"          
              },{                    
                "id":"460",         
                "name":"Widget 2",   
                "loc":"Shed"          
              },{                    
                "id":"460",         
                "name":"Widget s",   
                "loc":"Shed"          
              },{                      
                "id":"461",             
                "name":"Widget 2",       
                "loc":"Kitchen"           
              }]                           
        }';

    var jsObj=JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

Now I am going to insert data in jsobj, and data should reflect in indexed db aswell,
is it possible that I can sync javascript object with Indexed DB

Comment: Hi there, if you are just getting started with IDB please check out this demo first https://github.com/denimf/IndexedDbToDo, it has implemented all the basic functions of the api

Comment: When you say "I can sync javascript object" I'm guessing that you mean more than "how do I update an entry in IndexedDB," right? To "sync" an object to a database in IDB you just `add()` or `put()` a single entry or `update()` when using a cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to store that single list in persistent storage I would recommend you to use `Local Storage` instead of `IndexedDB`.

Here is a sample code which shows you how to store and retrieve your data:

```
// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('jsonData', JSON.stringify(jsonData));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jsonData'));
```

Comment: Thanks Deni, but I want to store and retrieve large amount of data, around 10 MB.

Comment: yeah you'll need IDB then, i've added link to example in the comments of the question